# MS, VB, SerialPort, Writing/Sending an Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, serial-port

I need to send an array `toOther` of `12` elements of numbers (e.g., `125`, `9`, `34`, etc.) through the serial port.  A helper had me format all as `String`, but I'd like to learn either way.

In `VB6`, (from which I'm translating) I could just send it, similar to the code which follows, but current `VB` rejects.

```
SP1.WriteLine(toFM)       
SP1.Write(toFM)
```

With `VB6`, I didn't need to send the array, incremental element by element in a loop, as I've seen in recent Searches for an answer.

Surely I'm missing a simple formatting requirement here.

Thanking Anyone in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both [`SerialPort.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and [`SerialPort.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) methods take a `String` as parameter to output. You will have to convert your array to a `String` as it has been suggested. The question is how the receiver expects the data. You could send each item one at a time as individual strings or create a delimited list from your array. You can use [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) to do so:

```
' Convert array to String
Dim value As String = String.Join(",", array)
```

Comment: Thank you!   It is String already, but it's good to know that it HAD to be converted to String.